# Textbox not taking new edited data instead taking post data

Tags: asp.net, session, post

I have made two pages Details.aspx and Default.aspx. I am passing a value from Details.aspx to Default.aspx by using session this is code

**Details Form**

```
Dim closeLink = CType(sender, Control)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(closeLink.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim firstCellText As String = row.Cells(0).Text
        Session("FAN") = firstCellText
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
```

**Default.aspx**

```
TextBoxFAN.Text = Session("FAN")


        If TextBoxFAN.Text <> "" Then
            Dim strConnString7 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ckd").ConnectionString
            Dim strQuery7 As String = "Select * From CKDMIS..FARegisterMaster Where FANumber=@FANumber"
            Dim con7 As New SqlConnection(strConnString7)
            Dim cmd7 As New SqlCommand()
            cmd7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FANumber", TextBoxFAN.Text)
            cmd7.CommandText = strQuery7
            cmd7.Connection = con7
            Try
                con7.Open()
                Dim ada7 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd7)
                Dim tbl7 As New DataTable()
                ada7.Fill(tbl7)
                DropDownListfactory.SelectedItem.Value = tbl7.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                TextBoxsubhead.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
                TextBoxType.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
                TextBoxbrand.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
                DropDownListdepartment.SelectedItem.Value = tbl7.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
                TextBoxserial.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(6).ToString()
                TextBoxwarranty.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(7).ToString()
                TextBoxdoa.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
                TextBoxlifetime.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(9).ToString()
                TextBoxcost.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(10).ToString()
                TextBoxdep.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(12).ToString()
                TextBoxaccdep.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(13).ToString()
                TextBoxnbv.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(14).ToString()
                TextBoxdesc.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(15).ToString()
                DropDownListhead.SelectedItem.Value = tbl7.Rows(0)(16).ToString()
                TextBoxModel.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(17).ToString()
                TextBoxFARef.Text = tbl7.Rows(0)(18).ToString()
                con7.Close()
                con7.Dispose()

                Dim strConnString8 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ckd").ConnectionString
                Dim strQuery8 As String = "Select C.ContactName as 'SupplierID', M.POID, M.GRNID From CKDMIS..FARegisterChild M Join (Select * from BitopiSplint..vwContacts Where ContactTypeId='CT002' and IsActive=1) C On M.SupplierID = C.ContactID Where M.FANumber=@FANumber"
                Dim con8 As New SqlConnection(strConnString8)
                Dim cmd8 As New SqlCommand()
                cmd8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FANumber", TextBoxFAN.Text)
                cmd8.CommandText = strQuery8
                cmd8.Connection = con8
                Try
                    con8.Open()
                    Dim ada As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd8)
                    Dim tbl1 As New DataTable()
                    ada.Fill(tbl1)
                    cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    GridViewDataFA.DataSource = tbl1
                    GridViewDataFA.DataBind()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                Finally
                    con8.Close()
                    con8.Dispose()
                End Try

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                con7.Close()
                con7.Dispose()
            End Try
        End If
```

**NOW THE PROBLEM**

After page loaded I am changing TextBoxbrand.Text and updating the the data based on a button click event but the textbox is taking post data not new data. don't know why or how

**Click event code**

```
 Dim a As String = DropDownListfactory.SelectedValue
        Dim b As String = TextBoxFARef.Text
        Dim c As String = TextBoxsubhead.Text
        Dim d As String = TextBoxType.Text
        Dim f As String = TextBoxbrand.Text
        Dim g As String = TextBoxModel.Text
        Dim h As String = DropDownListdepartment.SelectedValue
        Dim i As String = DropDownListhead.SelectedValue
        Dim j As String = TextBoxserial.Text
        Dim k As String = TextBoxwarranty.Text
        Dim l As String = TextBoxdoa.Text
        Dim m As String = TextBoxlifetime.Text
        Dim n As String = TextBoxcost.Text
        Dim o As String = TextBoxrate.Text
        Dim p As String = TextBoxdesc.Text

        If TextBoxFAN.Text = "" Or
                 a = "" Or
                 b = "" Or
                 c = "" Or
                 d = "" Or
                 f = "" Or
                 g = "" Or
                 h = "" Or
                 i = "" Or
                 j = "" Or
                 k = "" Or
                 l = "" Or
                 m = "" Or
                 n = "" Or
                 o = "" Or
                 p = "" Then

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter / load data properly');</script>")

        Else

            Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ckd").ConnectionString
            Dim strQuery As String = "Update CKDMIS..FARegisterMaster Set Factory=@Factory
      ,SubHead=@SubHead
      ,[Type]=@Type
      ,Brand=@Brand
      ,Department=@Department
      ,Serial=@Serial
      ,Warrenty=@Warrenty
      ,[Activation]=@Activation
      ,[LifeTime]=@LifeTime
      ,AcquisitionCost=@AcquisitionCost
      ,[Description]=@Description
      ,FACode=@FACode
      ,FARef=@FARef 
      ,ModelNo=@ModelNo Where FANumber=@FANumber"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FANumber", Request.QueryString.ToString())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Factory", a)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubHead", c)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", d)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", f)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", h)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", j)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Warrenty", Convert.ToDateTime(k))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activation", Convert.ToDateTime(l))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LifeTime", m)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcquisitionCost", Convert.ToDouble(n))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExchangeRate", o)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", p)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACode", i)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModelNo", g)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FARef", b)
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery
            cmd.Connection = con
            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Updated Successfully');</script>")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                con.Close()
                con.Dispose()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Please help!!!

Comment: I am changing TextBoxbrand.Text and updating the the data based on a button click event but the textbox is taking post data not new data . elaborate about this line

Comment: After loading the values i am editing the value of the textboxbrand and based on a button click event updating the data in the sql server. But it is always taking the load value not the edited one

Comment: what is value textboxbrand at time of loading? check do you have any event working on this text box or are you changing value from any other events?

Comment: simulate problem without database dependency and post here , so that we can check why it is happened.